# How do I stop Bash escaping my single quotes when I pass them via $@

Tags: bash, escaping

I have a bash script, which is trying to pass some incoming arguments to another program. It's basically:

```
set -x
echo $@
terraform $@
set +x
```

when executed (it get's called by another script, via docker, but I don't *think* that's important...), it outputs:

```
+ echo force-unlock e4014910-6b34-47a7-ad93-51842a63f0fa -var ''\''environment=qa'\'''
force-unlock e4014910-6b34-47a7-ad93-51842a63f0fa -var 'environment=qa'
+ terraform force-unlock e4014910-6b34-47a7-ad93-51842a63f0fa -var ''\''environment=qa'\'''
Too many command line arguments. Configuration path expected.
```

How can I get it to execute the echoed arguments:

```
terraform force-unlock e4014910-6b34-47a7-ad93-51842a63f0fa -var 'environment=qa'
```

and not

```
terraform force-unlock e4014910-6b34-47a7-ad93-51842a63f0fa -var ''\''environment=qa'\'''
```

Comment: Quote it: `terraform "$@"`

Comment: I get the same output, thanks though

Comment: the `set +x` output

Comment: Are you sure these extra quotes /aren't/ being added by your docker-call layer? I do something similar when I want to call something like `docker run bash -c "$@"` in order to preserve the spacing in $@

Comment: I think my example is wrong and giving a false-negative, I'm about to change from force-unlock to plan, and see if that works with the `""`

Comment: thanks folks, thats the problem.PEBKAS